# How can I return an undefined value with useMemo?

Tags: react-hooks, react-usememo, object-destructuring

I'm writing a custom React hook, and sometimes the values returned are undefined, sometimes not.

When I return them, no problems. When I want to return them using useMemo, it doesn't work.
What I'm doing wrong ?

[image]

```js
export function useCryptoDevs() {
    (...)
    const { data } = useContractReads((...))

    const numberOfNft = data?.[0]
    const maxNft = data?.[1]
    const presaleStarted = data?.[2]
    const presaleEnded = data?.[3]

    // this doesn't work :/
    // return (useMemo(() => { numberOfNft, maxNft, presaleStarted, presaleEnded }, [numberOfNft, maxNft, presaleStarted, presaleEnded]))

    // this work, returning undefined serverside and the values clientside
    return ({ numberOfNft, maxNft, presaleStarted, presaleEnded })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

```js
return (useMemo(() => ({ numberOfNft, maxNft, presaleStarted, presaleEnded }), [numberOfNft, maxNft, presaleStarted, presaleEnded]))
```

Also I would suggest to add some kind of fallback if data are undefined and then check this value if needed, eg.:

```js
const maxNft = data?.[1] || -1 //or some other "extreme" value
```

## Explanation

First of all, good to know is that these two are equivalent:

```js
() => (...) //Implicit return
() => {return ...} //Explicit return
```

The first parameter in useMemo hook is expected to be a function, so you have three options:

```js
useMemo(function hi() {return "Hello World"})
useMemo(() => ("Hello World"))
useMemo(() => {return "Hello World"})
```

Parentheses in arrow functions are (mostly) used to return an object (because all [primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) and variables are allowed to be used without parentheses, so the black sheep of the family is just the object)

```js
useMemo(() => 8) //implicit return | single-line
useMemo(() => (8)) //implicit return | multi-line
useMemo(() => {return 8}) //explicit return
//instead of 8, there could be any of the primitives, e.g.: string "Hello World"

const foo = 8;
useMemo(() => foo)
useMemo(() => (foo))
useMemo(() => {return foo})

const bar = {intval: 8, strval: "Hello World"};
useMemo(() => bar)
useMemo(() => (bar))
useMemo(() => {return bar})
//we are returning a variable here, not bare object
```

But to the interpreter the `() => { maxNft, numberOfNft }` looks like function with explicit return that I mentioned above: `() => { return ... }`

So you just have to make it clear that it is an object, some specific returned value, not an function with explicit return

```js
useMemo(() => ({ maxNft, numberOfNft }), []) //implicit return of object
useMemo(() => {return { maxNft, numberOfNft }}, []) //explicit return of object
```

Comment: Thank you so much !!
Why theses parenthesis are needed ? I'm just returning an object...
do you have a link/a concept for me to dig my misunderstanding of what exactly happening on this line ?

Comment: @Fabien Explanation added, hope that clears things up for you!

Comment: Ok everything is clear rn. Thank you very much guy !